# Select SUM if NULL - UPDATE "0"

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

I have got this code which `SELECTS SUM` and then `UPDATE` this result somewhere. But the issue is when there are `no results found for SELECT SUM(castka)` with those conditions.

I'm wondering how to make `Exception for DBNull` if there wasn't found any result and `UPDATE  "0"` instead. As I'm not that long programming would anyone please help me solve this out?

Thank you so much for your time.

```
private void btn_zavri_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            spojeni.Close();
            SqlCommand sc2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUM(castka) AS sumcastka FROM kliplat WHERE akce='" + zakce.Text + "' AND rocnik='" + rocnik + "'", spojeni);
            spojeni.Open();
            int vysledek2 = Convert.ToInt32(sc2.ExecuteScalar());
            SqlCommand sc3 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE zajezd SET s_prijmy=@s_prijmy WHERE akce='" + zakce.Text + "' AND rocnik='" + rocnik + "'", spojeni);
            spojeni.Close();
            sc3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s_prijmy", vysledek2);
            spojeni.Open();
            sc3.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("" + ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            spojeni.Close();
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you want to achieve?

```
SELECT ISNULL(SUM(castka), 0) AS sumcastka FROM kliplat
```

Comment: Yes! Exactly, thank you so much for your answer and time, I will accept in few minutes.

Comment: This is not exact, what if the `SUM(castka)` is not null but `ZERO`? We can't know if the `WHERE` condition is met or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
try
    {

        spojeni.Close();
        SqlCommand sc2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUM(castka) AS sumcastka FROM kliplat WHERE akce='" + zakce.Text + "' AND rocnik='" + rocnik + "'", spojeni);
        spojeni.Open();
        object obj = sc2.ExecuteScalar();
        int vysledek2 = obj == null ? 0  : Convert.ToInt32(obj);
        if(obj != null){
          SqlCommand sc3 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE zajezd SET s_prijmy=@s_prijmy WHERE akce='" + zakce.Text + "' AND rocnik='" + rocnik + "'", spojeni);
          spojeni.Close();
          sc3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s_prijmy", vysledek2);
          spojeni.Open();
          sc3.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
//....
```

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
  int vysledek2 = Convert.ToInt32(sc2.ExecuteScalar());
```

to

```
 object test = sc2.ExecuteScalar();
 if(test != DBNull.Value && test!=null)
 {
     //rest of your code
     int vysledek2 = Convert.ToInt32(test);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the sum function with ISNULL and return 0 when there are no records:

```
SELECT ISNULL(SUM(castka), 0) AS sumcastka
```